# Error importing bootstrap with js files into my maven project

Tags: java, html, twitter-bootstrap, maven, web

When downloading and copying the files of the latest bootstrap version to my maven project, an error appears in all java script files.

Apparently it is because of syntax errors but I have not changed any line of code in those files:

[image]

How can I fix the error so that I get the js loaded in the bootstrap components I use on my site?

Comment: There are no issues with the javascript files. What happen when you run your appllicaiton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven has nothing to deal with the errors you see.

They are simply an issue/notification of the code inspector of Eclipse, the IDE your are using.

You could try disabling errors following next instructions:

1. Go to Eclipse > Preferences > JavaScript > Validators > Errors/Warnings.
2. Uncheck “Enable JavaScript semantic validation”.